# What am I missing with PHP code or CSV file?

Tags: php, mysql, database

**'LINES TERMINATED BY' PROBLEM - PHP, SQL database, CSV file'**

Im learning how to update database with PHP, from local file.
It is working fine, except just the last entry from my CSV file is inserted into all fields in database table.

I've tried inspecting CSV with HEX, and also all thinkable versions of LINES TERMINATED BY (\r\n, \n etc.).

Here is my [CSV file](https://utvikling.kjettamoen.no/try1.csv)

This image shows the code was executed properly.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9xC1.jpg

Here is my PHP code:

```
$dbhost = 'hidden';
$dbuser = 'hidden';
$dbpass = 'hidden';
$dbname = 'hidden';

// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

// check connection
if(!$conn){
    echo 'Connection error: '. mysqli_connect_error();
}

// create temporary table
$create = 'CREATE TABLE tmp
(
   name_id varchar(255),
   phone varchar(255),
   INDEX (name_id)
)'; 

// check if creation was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $create)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully CREATE.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $create. " . mysqli_error($conn);
} ?><br><br><?php

// load data from local file into temp table
$load = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'try1.csv' 
INTO TABLE tmp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(@name_id, @phone)" ;

// check if load was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $load)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully LOAD.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $load. " . mysqli_error($conn);
} ?><br><br><?php

// set/update temp table with info from csv file
$set = "UPDATE tmp SET
name_id = @name_id,
phone = @phone  "
;

// check if update was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $set)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully SET.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $set. " .   mysqli_error($conn);
}


mysqli_close($conn);
```

I would expect all 4 entries in CSV file to be inserted, instead I get the last rows values in all 4 entries in database.

This image shows the result in my database table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycRzl.png

Comment: The poroblem is with your update query. You update all records to the last value, just comment that line and don't do the update

Comment: Should I comment out the entire update query? I tried that, and this was the result in my table: https://imgur.com/SsXucWy.

All fields with (NULL) values.

Comment: Your update query should contain a where clause so it only update one (the correct) line at a time

Comment: @Will Sounds like a good idea. Any suggestion as to how I could make sure it goes through unique IDs one at a time?

Comment: Second thought, it may be way more simple : why do you need to update the data ? You already loaded them in your table
(sorry I don't have what's needed to run your code)

Comment: Thats what another poster suggested also (wherexdid his comment go?!), but after trying the code without the update query, my table returned (null) values in all field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify two things in your code:

1. You don't need to update your data if you just have added the data.
2. The names of the columns in your load data are incorrect (you shoulkd remove the @), so you are inserting null lines. (If you only have those two columns in your table, you don't need to specify the names, so you can remove them too.)

Modify your code as:

```
$dbhost = 'hidden';
$dbuser = 'hidden';
$dbpass = 'hidden';
$dbname = 'hidden';

// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_options($conn, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

// check connection
if(!$conn){
    echo 'Connection error: '. mysqli_connect_error();
}

// create temporary table
$create = 'CREATE TABLE tmp
(
   name_id varchar(255),
   phone varchar(255),
   INDEX (name_id)
)'; 

// check if creation was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $create)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully CREATE.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $create. " . mysqli_error($conn);
} ?><br><br><?php

// load data from local file into temp table
$load = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'try1.csv' 
INTO TABLE tmp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(name_id, phone)" ;

// check if load was successful
if(mysqli_query($conn, $load)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully LOAD.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $load. " . mysqli_error($conn);
} ?><br><br><?php


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Cheers! That was it! Thank you, @nacho!